# Unable to access object property php

Tags: php

I have the following object in a rewards-object.php file:

```
<?php

$rewards_obj_data = array(
    array(
    'reward_id' => 0,
    'reward_mile_text' => "mile 0",
    'reward_title' => "Tag Connected Watch",
    'reward_img' => "../assets/rewards/rewards-1.jpg",
    'reward_apr' => "Representative 18.9% APR (variable)",
    'reward_cta_url' => "rewards/claimReward.jsp&rewardID=0"/* + auth cookie details */,
    ),
    array(
    'reward_id' => 1,
    'reward_mile_text' => "mile 1",
    'reward_title' => "Tag Connected Watch",
    'reward_img' => "../assets/rewards/rewards-1.jpg",
    'reward_apr' => "Representative 18.9% APR (variable)",
    ),    
    array(
    'reward_id' => 2,
    'reward_mile_text' => "mile 2",
    'reward_title' => "Tag Connected Watch",
    'reward_img' => "../assets/rewards/rewards-1.jpg",
    'reward_apr' => "Representative 18.9% APR (variable)",
    ),    
    array(
    'reward_id' => 3,
    'reward_mile_text' => "mile 3",
    'reward_title' => "Tag Connected Watch",
    'reward_img' => "../assets/rewards/rewards-1.jpg",
    'reward_apr' => "Representative 18.9% APR (variable)",
    ),    
    array(
    'reward_id' => 4,
    'reward_mile_text' => "mile 4",
    'reward_title' => "Tag Connected Watch",
    'reward_img' => "../assets/rewards/rewards-1.jpg",
    'reward_apr' => "Representative 18.9% APR (variable)",
    ),    
);

?>
```

I am trying to access its properties in another for loop:

```
<?php
    require '../api/rewards-object.php';

   // in between here I make some API calls to retrive an array of objects which I have named $rewardsAPIResponse

    // parse http request
    $decode_rewardsAPIResponse = json_decode($rewardsAPIResponse);

    /* for loop */
    foreach($decode_rewardsAPIResponse as $key=>$value){

        $IdFromApi = $value->rewardID;

         $test = json_encode($rewards_obj_data[$IdFromApi]->reward_title);
        echo $test;
    };
?>
```

The idea here is to use the id of the objects that is returned from the API to fetch objects in the rewards-object.php file.

At the moment if I replace this line:

```
     $test = json_encode($rewards_obj_data[$IdFromApi]->reward_id);
    echo $test;
```

with:

```
     $test = json_encode($rewards_obj_data[$IdFromApi]);
    echo $test;
```

Then it fetches the objects no problem! The problem lies with me trying to access the objects property such as `reward_title`. Here it returns me a value of null. I have been playing around with the json_encode part as I think that could be where the issue lies but so far everything i've tried doesn't work. Any ideas where i've gone wrong?

Comment: Its not an object, its an array. You might want to use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`

Comment: Unlike JavaScript, arrays in PHP are not objects and they don't share the `[]` syntax at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$rewards_obj_data is an array, and so is the content. But you try to access it like you would an object. Its an array, not an object. 
This would be the correct way:

```
$rewards_obj_data[$IdFromApi]['reward_id']
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see object, but two-dimensional array.
Access your value as `$rewards_obj_data[$IdFromApi]['reward_title'];`

Answer (score 0):

Your array is not an object. In PHP arrays may exist have integer and string keys, perhaps that is the confusion.

```
echo $rewards_obj_data[0]['reward_id']; // 0

foreach($rewards_obj_data as $value){
  echo $value['reward_id'];
}

// Convert array to to string, converting arrays to objects.
$json = json_encode($rewards_obj_data, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

// Convert json to a PHP object.
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach($data as $obj){
  echo $obj->reward_id;
}
```